# About Access Specifier in C++

Tags: c++, class

I was reading a C++ handbook and in a chapter regarding the creation of a custom string class I got into this code:

```
string& string::operator = (const string& Str)
{
char* temp = new char[Str.m_Length];
m_Length = Str.m_Length;
memcpy(temp,Str.m_Data,m_Length);
delete [ ] m_Data;
m_Data = temp;
return *this; 
}
```

It is about the implementation of the copy constructor.
Everything works properly and I can't complain about its efficiency, but what I don't get is how it is possible to read m_Length and m_Data variables from the Str string, since they are private members of the class.
I'll show you the class interface:

```
class string
{
public:
string();
string (const string& Str);
string& operator = (const string& Str);
~string();
string(char* p);
private:
short m_Length;
char* m_Data;
};
```

Is that possible because we called Str in the function as a reference value?
Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access specifiers are relative to a class, not to instances of that class. `private` means private to a class, not private to an object of that type. That is, any object of type `string` can access the `private` members of any other `string` object.

"Doesn't this break encapsulation?" I hear you cry. Actually, no. We tend to measure the encapsulation of a class by the number of functions that would break if you were to change the internal implementation of that class. The member functions of `string` are already tightly coupled to the private members, so no encapsulation is lost by allowing access to the private members of other objects of the same type. For more on encapsulation, read [“How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation”](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

I may also wonder why C++ is weird like this, but you might be surprised to find that the same is true in Java, C#, and many other languages.

Comment: "Access specifiers are relative to a class, not to instances of that class." - that's true in this case, and most cases, but not true for protected members of base classes (as that would prevent other derived classes enforcing any invariants around the protected data members).

Comment: Thank you for your kind and enlightening answers. Yep, the concept is not that immediate for a newbie, but your explanations are pretty clear and straight.